# How to deal with encryption plain text on server and decryption on client?

Tags: c#, typescript, encryption, cryptography, client-server

I have some sensitive details and since GDPR, everything needs to be encrypted.
So I`m struggling with a problem.
If for password or register details I can use some kind of a hash algorithm, because I check matching on server-side, now I need to encrypt a plain-text.

I just read about some algorithms like RSA, DES, AES and so on, but what I didn`t understand was how to implement on client-server architecture.

So, firstly I encrypt plain text on server using any of these algorithms.
After that I need to decrypt on client side, but I need the key.
This is the moment I dunno what to do. Ok, we can encrypt the key and send to the client, but how to save the key forever? 
Add a column in database and store the key there? And when we want to get that information, encrypt the key, send to the client, decrypt the key, decrypt the crypted text?
And so on?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but what sort of plaintext are you encrypting? You only have to encrypt user-critical data as per GDPR. And most of the time, if not for passwords or keys a https connection to your server should be sufficient.

Comment: Medical history for a patient... consultations, health conditions and so on. About my issue I was thinking to encrypt the key and store in database.

Comment: For medical information it's a must-have I agree. Is your Client a JS Website or a Desktop Client?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that. I`m using .NET core (c#) for server and for client TS Website (Angular).

Comment: Okay should the data should be encrypted so that the server-client communication is encrypted on top of TLS or should the data be encrypted in a way that non other than the user (not even sysadmin) can view the data?

Comment: My project is for graduation and is locally, so the data should be encrypted on server-client communication and it`s enough.

Comment: Since it's for graduation I shouldn't be helping you, but how I would go about this is, I would generate a RSA key pair on the client side when the user initiates his session and share the public key with the server. The server then encrypts the data with said public key, sends it to the client, which then is able to decrypt it using their own secret private key. With web based applications you can't really trust the client, but since it's not for a production environment, you should be fine.

Comment: I can`t find any library or documentation to implement RSA :).

Comment: @TobiasTengler Doing what you suggest is pointless - TLS is more than enough in the situation you describe.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I mentioned TLS / https 2 times during commenting, but it didn't seem to be enough for the questioner.

Comment: It isn't. Generally you'd use TLS for the transport security and also encrypt data at rest, separately. I'm glad you mentioned this is a graduation project, because you'd hire a consultant for real medical records, right?

Comment: Is not a problem if medical history is kept as plain text in database?

Comment: You should probably tell your boss to hire a security consultant. Why would he even task someone who knows nothing about data security with job???

Comment: He is my teacher, not my boss. It`s all about GDPR, I think the problem is that the developer can access sensitive data directly from database and somehow I should have encoded, not about the way of transmitting data between parties. Thank you guys anyway, now I know about TLS and how is functioning.